# How to parse attachment values with strongGrid inbound webhook

Tags: parsing, .net-core, sendgrid, stronggrid

Hello there I have setup successfully inbound webhook with strongGrid in net core 3.1.
The endpoint gets called and I want to parse value inside the attachment which is csv file.

The code I am using is following

```
            var parser = new WebhookParser();
            var inboundEmail = await parser.ParseInboundEmailWebhookAsync(Request.Body).ConfigureAwait(false);

            await _emailSender.SendEmailAsyncWithSendGrid("info@mydomain.com", "ParseWebhook1", inboundEmail.Attachments.First().Data.ToString());
```

Please note I am sending an email as I don t know how to debug webhook with sendgrid as I am not aware of any cli.
but this line apparently is not what I am looking for
`inboundEmail.Attachments.First().Data.ToString()`
I am getting this on my email

```
Id = a3e6a543-2aee-4ffe-a36a-a53k95921998, Tag = HttpMultipartParser.MultipartFormDataParser.ParseStreamAsync, Length = 530 bytes
```

the csv I need to parse has 3 fields Sku productname and quantity I'd like to get sku values.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.Data` property contains a Stream and invoking `ToString` on a stream object does not return its content. The proper way to read the content of a stream in C# is something like this:

```cs
var streamReader = new StreamReader(inboundEmail.Attachments.First().Data);
var attachmentContent = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

As far as parsing the CSV, there are literally thousands of projects on [GitHub](https://github.com/search?l=C%23&q=csv&type=Repositories) and hundreds on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=csv) with the keyword 'CSV'. I'm sure one of them will fit your needs.